# "Extra argument in call" with AVCaptureDevice

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, avcapturedevice

Getting Error on this line: [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYhht.png)

```
let backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back)
```

[another screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYhht.png)
 of code

Comment: It is available after iOS 10, are you using a lower version?

Comment: You code looks correct if you are using Swift4

Comment: i am using for ios 11 only Swift 4

Comment: Try cleaning your project or try to isolate your problem.  You need to add some more context to your question. Note that this method returns an optional so you should use guard or if let to unwrap the returned value.

Comment: @user7041947 don't add screen shots to your question. Add the actual code

Comment: You code again as I said looks like it should be compiling.

Comment: i added screenshot of my code , but it not showing i dnt know why

Comment: @user7041947: The image you attached have `withDeviceType` argument label, but the code in your question doesn't have that label. Code in your question is correct, but the code in your screenshot is wrong

Comment: added updated screenshot